# how to integrate stripe payment gateway in angular js

Tags: angularjs, stripe-payments

I am using angular version 1.6.4 and i am trying to integrate stripe payment gateway in it. The problem that i am facing during integration is that the package that i am using is giving an error  require is not defined. the library  that i used to  integrate stripe payment gateway in project are is on the [link](https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-stripe)

npm package that i am using is

> npm install --save angular-stripe

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes angular can force you to declare "require". I use this when that happens...

```
declare var require: any;
```